# Angular - pass $scope function to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm passing a controller $scope function to a directive through an html attribute, but for some reason the directive thinks that the function is a string. Any hints?

HTML

```
<modal show='createCustomer' create-new-customer='createNewCustomer()'></modal>
```

Directive

```
function modalDialog() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope:{
      createNewCustomer: '&'
    },
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.createNewCustomer = attrs.createNewCustomer;
      console.log(typeof scope.createNewCustomer)
    },
    templateUrl: "./views/directive_templates/modal.html"
  };
}
```

$scope function

```
 $scope.createNewCustomer = function(){
    alert('yo')
  }
```

Best,
Austin

Comment: dont set it in your link function, putting it in your `scope {}` option is already creating it on your directive's scope

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be:

```
<modal show='createCustomer' create-new-customer='createNewCustomer'></modal>
```

It is most likely invoking the function immediately and passing in the result

Answer (score 0):

In your directive, you already have `scope.createNewCustomer` bound to the function, through the use of the `&` parameter in your isolate scope.  However, you actually overwrite the function with the string value when you re-assign it through the `attrs`.  `attrs` is simply an array of key value pairs that are the string representation of each attribute in the element.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs directive lets you to use '&' method in scope with 2 ways.First way lets you to pass argument inside your isolated directive.Second one lets you to pass arguments outside of directive but to call INSIDE ISOLATED DIRECTIVE.Like

```
<div my-dir func="myFunc(arg1,arg2,..)"></div>
<div my-dir func="myFunc(value1,value2,..)"></div>
```

If you want more here is a cool article with examples:

http://www.w3docs.com/snippets/angularjs/angularjs-directive-scope-method.html